# Read weight from google fit

Tags: android, google-fit

I can't read a weight from Google Fit.
When I make request to Google Fit for weight I get only name of weight field (weight) but DataPoints size is 0. What is wrong?

code:

```
DataReadRequest dataReadRequest = queryFitnessData();

DataReadResult dataReadResult = Fitness.HistoryApi.readData(getApiClient(), dataReadRequest)
                .await(1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
////////
private static DataReadRequest queryFitnessData() {
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    Date date = new Date();
    calendar.setTime(date);
    long endTime = calendar.getTimeInMillis();
    calendar.add(Calendar.YEAR, -1);
    long startTime = calendar.getTimeInMillis();

    DataReadRequest dataReadRequest = new DataReadRequest.Builder()
            .read(DataType.TYPE_WEIGHT)
            .setTimeRange(startTime, endTime, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .build();

    return dataReadRequest;
}
```

Comment: can you share getApiClient() method?

Comment: @SARATHV yep. 
[click here :)](https://gist.github.com/TemMax/31ceef341aec329265b6a2f7bc516a02)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you have weight added in the timerange you specified.Can you try

```
DataReadRequest dataReadRequest = new DataReadRequest.Builder()
            .read(DataType.TYPE_WEIGHT)
            .setTimeRange(1, endTime, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .setLimit(1)
            .build();
```

Comment: Oh thanks. Its works! But why I don't get my weight if I changed it ~6-7 monthes ago? I decrement a year from today, but...